# Custom component comparison in flex

Tags: apache-flex, comparison, custom-component

I have a custom component called Tag

```
package bin {
  public class Tag  {
    public var count:int;
    public var text:String;

    public function Tag() {}
  }
}
```

I have a bunch of these tags in a two arrays.  I want to be able to call

```
arr0.indexOf( arr1[0] )  //line 1
// or 
arr0[0] == arr1[0]       //line 2
```

and only have the text field be compared.
ie

```
tag{text:"hi", count:0} == tag{text:"hi", count:5}
```

Even though the counts differ the above result would be true, likewise if the two tags are in the different lists I want them to match up to each other as would in line 1

In java the solution would be to implement the comparable interface and overwrite the compare method to suit my needs.  I could not find any documentation on such a solution in flex.  Nor did my attempts at making a compare method work.

I am using Flex 3 fyi

Comment: Can't you use arr0[0].text == arr1[0].text ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [Operator Overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading), and according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/818750/259457), it doesn't look like you can do that in Flex. But, you can write an `equals()` method in your custom component to compare the two.